# Grails GORM Service class Testing withNewSession()

Tags: hibernate, grails, grails-orm, integration-testing

I am trying to update my test since I made a change on my service class.
In a service method I added  ("withNewSession")

```
Domain.withNewSession {
  .. ...
  domain.save()
}
```

Since I am using the "withNewSession", I am getting method missing exception as this Domain is mocked in my test class.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

withNewSession method is not allowed by unit testing. Use inside your test class:

```
@org.junit.Before
void before() {
    DomainClazz.metaClass.static.withNewSession = {Closure c -> c.call() }
}
```

Comment: This solved my problem. Love the meta-programming capabilities of Groovy :)

Answer (score 0):

You should test persistence with *integration* tests, not unit tests. Use domain class mocking only when testing controllers or other classes that depend on domain classes, but where the domain classes aren't the class under test.

Comment: The service method does some business logic and I am trying to test that. The reason I had to add Domain.withNewSession around the logic was because I am running the method in multiple thread scenario.